# Swift - Same protocol for two different classes

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I want to use the same protocol for two different classes. It is for two `UIStoryboardSegue` classes, the normal one and the unwind segue. In my first class `GameSegue.swift`, I've declared this protocol

```
@objc protocol ViewControllerWithBackgroundImage {

    var backgroundImage: UIImageView { set get }

}
```

I use this protocol to have access to the ViewControllers property `backgroundImage`. In the first class `GameSegue.swift`, the normal segue, the `backgroundImage` animates `10 px` up. So in the second class `GameSegueUnwind.swift`, I want to do the same thing backwards, move the background `10 px`down. But to get access to the `backgroundImage` property I need this protocol. Therefore it would be useful, to not declare another protocol, but instead use the same.

Any idea how this is possible?

Comment: What have you tried? If a protocol is declared in one file, it's available everywhere inside a project.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I missed something. Of course I can use this property also in the unwind class. Shall I delete this question?

Comment: No worries! Probably a good idea.

Comment: Hm, I tried it again but I doesn't work. If I call this line `self.destinationViewController.backgroundImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -60)` in `GameSegueUnwind.swift` it gives me an error: `'UIImage?' does not have a member named 'transform'`. So this is not the solution. I called the same line in the `GameSegue.swift` and it gives no error. Another thing, that is strange is, that the autocompletion shows me that the property is of type `UIImage??` and not `UIImageView`, as it should be. What is that?

Comment: However you're using `ViewControllerWithBackgroundImage` in your `GameSegue` class, you should be able to do the same in your `GameSegueUnwind` class. In order for you to access `backgroundView`, you'd need to cast `self.destinationController` to `ViewControllerWithBackgroundImage` - are you doing that somewhere in the first case?

Comment: No, I've searched for it but I haven't found anything. Can you tell me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68678/discussion-between-nate-cook-and-codey).

Comment: Can you wait 30 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second class just declare a new delegate variable

```
class GameSegueUnwind {
     var secondDelegate: ViewControllerWithBackgroundImage?
}
```

and you will be able to access the function in any other class that conforms to the protocol. Of course, in the conforming class remember to declare it has the delegate handler in the prepare for segue method

```
destinatonViewController.secondDelegate = self
```